# Neo4j HTTP API transaction timeout period

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j HTTP API for importing data to neo4j. I know according to [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#http-api-transactional) document timeout period can be set globally by setting **dbms.rest.transaction.idle_timeout** property. 
However instead of doing this can we set timeout dynamically for transaction when begin the transaction. Please see begin transaction [API](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#rest-api-begin-a-transaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the timeout dynamically when you create a transaction.

However, you can dynamically *extend* the global timeout period for an active transaction by using it to send an empty list of statements to the server, which will restart the clock for the timeout period. [See here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#rest-api-reset-transaction-timeout-of-an-open-transaction) for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can achieve this by using the [APOC extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)'s `apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed` method. Check this link https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/cypher-timeboxed/

You can download the [JAR file for the APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) library. Then you should put the JAR file under the `/plugins` folder then restart your neo4j database.

For every cypher query you executed with HTTP, you can wrap them with a "timeboxed" expression. Check the below codes.

```
const cql = "MATCH (n)-[e]-() RETURN n,e limit 10";
const timeout = 10000;
const q = `CALL apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed("${cql}", {}, ${timeout})`;
```